# Picklist field is disabled but profile and layout shows editible

Tags: security, picklist, permissions

I have a picklist field on a custom object that is disabled (grayed out) when I am editing a record on that custom object for a user in a profile that should have write access to that field.

I have verified the user's profile should have the ability to edit the field under "Field Accessibility" for that field (field-level security). I also have verified that the field is not "Read Only" on all of the object's page layouts.

This field is editable using the System Administrator profile.

Where/what else might I check?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was due to the object having two record types with incorrectly configured picklist values. `Record Type A` had all of the picklist values. `Record Type B` had none. Not having any is an invalid state. When you try to remove *all* values from a picklist for a given record type, you'll get the following error:

> At least one value must be selected

So, I believe this problem may have somehow been introduced via deployment to the test environment where this problem was found.

By adding the picklist values to `Record Type B`, the problem was solved.

Most interesting is the fact that regardless of which record type you were editing a record for, the picklist would be disabled, most likely caused by the invalid state mentioned above.

Answer (score 1):

Go to Setup -> Create -> Objects and then click edit next to the field. It's almost certainly FLS (field-level security) - verify that the profile has write access there.

Comment: Thanks Bri. But as I mentioned, I have already checked field level security and the user's profile has Editable access to that field.

Comment: No you didn't, you said "Field Accessibility," then edited your post and added that, lol. But you're 100% sure "Read-Only" is unchecked in the two-column view when you go to the page titled "Set Field-Level Security?"

Comment: Thanks Bri. Absolutely sure... Ready Only is not checked for that profile. Also, I thought Field Accessibility implied field-level security.

Comment: AFAIK (I've been known to be wrong tho :P) it pretty much has to be on the profile or FLS level. The other sharing tools only extend access, not restrict it. It's a pure picklist field? Not a formula or roll-up summary?